# Bookmarklets in Chrome's Bookmark Bar

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, bookmarklet

A bookmarklet I've developed and use in other browsers does not work in Chrome. More specifically, I've added it to the Chrome Bookmarks Bar, and it will not fire on Chrome's default home screen, regardless of whether I click it on the Bookmarks Bar, or in the drop down Bookmarks menu. ***Yet***, when I use it when Chrome is on any other page, it works just fine. Here is the redacted bookmarklet:

```
javascript:window.location.href="http://part.of."+prompt("Website:")+".the.web.site.com";
```

Simple, right? Yet, why doesn't this work within Chrome? Safari, even when it's on its Top Sites "meta page" responds to this bookmarklet without issue.

Comment: And, btw, I've tried this where I've even simplified the bookmarklet to this form, and it still doesn't work:


`javascript:window.location.href="http://stackoverflow.com";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's a deliberate security feature of Chrome, according to this posting:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=98871#c2

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be it. Do you know if they allow Chrome Extensions to run on `chrome://` pages?

Comment: Hmm... Not sure. I just tried a few, with not entirely positive results. Two that I tried (including one of my own) didn't work at all, and the Evernote one brings up a message saying "Clipping from this location is not supported".

Comment: Ben, you can manually add a JS snippet as a bookmark. Just prepend your script with `javascript:`. Just tried it in the latest version of Chrome and works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, tailor it to meet your needs, it works in the standard new tab page.

```
javascript:search_terms=prompt('Search terms?');window.location='http://www.google.com/search?q='+search_terms+'site:history.com';
```